# Let threads read shared variable until modified

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple class which doesn't require a thread to obtain a lock while reading from my shared object. However if any particular thread tries to modify this shared object, then no thread can read from the object. Bellow is an example of my class.

```
package com.taylor.wall.core.domain;

import java.util.List;

public class Wall {

    // This needs to be synchronized and concurrent
    private List<Post> posts;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void addPost(Post post) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            posts.add(post);
        }
    }

    // Unfortunately this is wasteful, because for threads must now acquire lock before reading
    public List<Post> getPost() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return posts;
        }
    }
}
```

What would be a better alternative? The wall object is shared amongst many threads. Also declaring my list to be final static is not a good idea because the list is too big to re-create and set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is inherently unsafe, because it could still result in updates to `posts` in one thread that are only partially read in another. For instance, imagine this situation:

1. Thread-A calls `getPosts()` and gets a copy of the list. Let's say it never modifies it -- let's even say you wrapped it in a `Collections.unmodifiableList` to ensure that it's never modified.
2. Thread-B calls `addPost(somePost)`.
3. Thread-A uses the reference it got from the first step above.

In this case, in step 3 we have a list that's been updated in one thread (thread-B) and read in another thread (thread-A) without any memory synchronization. You could read partial updates in the `posts` list, in any one of the `Post` objects it contains, in any object referenced by one of those `Post` objects, etc.

Your two options are:

- Use a thread-safe `List` implementation.
- Create new copies of the `List`. If you do this, you could:

  - Create those new lists on each `addPost` (and return that wrapped in a `Collections.unmodifiedList` from `getPosts`, along with synchronization as I mentioned in my comment on EJP's answer); or
  - Create the new list on each read (within the synchronized block).
  - Which of those is faster depends on usage: do you get more reads, or more writes?

Unfortunately, there's not much in the way of thread-safe lists. You could use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which (as the name implies) creates an internal copy on each write, and is thus similar to the first copy-variant I mentioned above. You could also take the original `posts` list and wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedList`. If you do that, you should make sure that nobody else has a copy of that `posts` list, pre-wrapped. If they might (that is, if you get the list passed into your constructor), then you should first make a copy of that list, then wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedList`, and then return that as an `unmodifiableList` from `getPosts`. And if you take that approach, you don't even need to do the synchronization yourself!

```
private final List<Post> posts;

public  Wall(List<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(posts));
}

public void addPost(Post post) {
    posts.add(post); // internally synchronized
}

public List<Post> getPosts() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(post);
}
```

If you do that, make sure that the reader thread knows that the list might be modified *at any time*. This means it can't check a condition and then act on it, unless it's got a lock on that list:

```
if (!posts.isEmpty() {
    // another thread could clear the thread right now!
    posts.get(0); // could fail
}
```

If all you do is to add posts (ie, there's not a method like `Wall.removePost`), then you shouldn't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't return the list at all, as you can't tell what the caller is going to do with it. You should provide all the list operations yourself, with locks as required. Or else provide the list as read-only via `Colllections.unmodifiableList()` and only provide the update operations. If you really think contention is going to be an issue, this is a case for a [`java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: So could I instead leave the lock on addPost, but take out the synchronized(lock) for getPosts and replace return posts with " return Collections.unmodifiableList(posts) " ? I just don't want to touch posts, or read from it if it is in the process of being changed. It seems like a unsafe thread thing to do, unless having that variable in a critical section prevents it from being used everywhere else.

Comment: You still need the `synchronized(lock)` (or something else, like the read-write lock mentioned in the other answer) to ensure memory synchronization -- otherwise, the reader thread could see only some of the updates that the writer thread did. For instance, the list is an `ArrayList`, the reader thread might see an update to the internal `size` variable but not to the internal array -- or it could see that internal array updated, but part of the updates to the `Post`s it references.

Comment: Actually, even returning the `unmodifiableList` isn't enough: the reader could hold on to that list reference for a while, and in the meanwhile another update happens on it. If the underlying `posts` isn't thread-safe, then that will break the `unmofidiableList`.

Comment: Also remember unmodifiableList does not protect you from the always irritating ConcurrentModificationException.  If you're really passing it off to unknown code, a full copy is best :(

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.concurrent package has a ReadWriteLock in it that you can use to have exclusive writes and non-exclusive reads.

```
    private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void addPost(Post post) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            posts.add(post);
        } finally {
          lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public List<Post> getPost() {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try {
//You did not tell us what type of list posts is or what actually happens to it.
//Just locking around returning the pointer only forces other threads to see the updates
//you've made.  It doesn't stop them from then attempting unsafe things on it after it's
//returned.
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Post>(posts));
        } finally {
          lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is quite dangerous, you `return posts` , so now the caller has access to the posts List, and can use it while it's being updated.

Comment: Well, it's not pointless -- it'll provide a happens-before edge relative to another thread adding to the list. But yes, returning the list is dangerous. From the [ReadWriteLock javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html): `a thread successfully acquiring the read lock will see all updates made upon previous release of the write lock.`

Comment: I don't know why you say it's completely pointless.  It has significant functional consequences.  Given 'posts' isn't initialized at all in the example, how can you tell if it's safe or not?  I took the thing as pseudo code and tried to answer the question re: how to get around synchronizing reads, sorry we disagree.

Comment: It provides a happens-before edge for the value of the list reference variable. As regards what happens to the list itself, it does nothing.

Comment: @EJP No, it's a full happens-before edge. The thread acquiring the read locks "will see **all updates**" from the thread that had the write lock.